# regex: retrieve which pattern matched

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to infer the pattern from a list of email to see if the email id follows firstname.lastname or lastname.firstname pattern. I can match email by using an 'or' with the possible patterns like below

```
re.match("|".join([regex_pat1, regex_pat2]), email)
```

Once I get a match, how do I know which regex pattern string from list matched the target email?

edit: example

```
import re
email = "sam.rohn@gmail.com"

patt = ["sam.rohn@gmail.com", "rohn.sam@gmail.com"]

re.match("|".join(patt), email)
```

This gives me a match object
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 30), match='sam.rohn@gmail.com'>

What I want to know is which one of my pattern from my 'patt' list matched

Comment: Could you include an example of the input and expected output?

Comment: Note that your code will also match `sambrohn@gmailecom`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parentheses to enclose your patterns and identify your match with a matching group as in

```
patt = ["(sam\.rohn@gmail\.com)", "(rohn\.sam@gmail\.com)"]
```

see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

Honestly your question confused me, because if you match successfully that the pattern should equal to `email`. And you can check if it follows firstname.lastname or lastname.firstname pattern through `print(email in patt)` since you have `email` and `patt`.

In regex, `.` will matche all character that except for  line terminators(`\n`) . If you only want to match the `.` then add a backslash `\.` or `[.]#(not recommended)`